# Xcode 11 - Swift Package Manager can't find Manifest

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm working on updating some pods I use to also be compatible with SPM and I've updated this one https://github.com/trusk89/SwiftForms.git but when I try to add it to the project I'm using it in, I keep getting 
`Showing All Messages
: https://github.com/trusk89/SwiftForms.git has no Package.swift manifest for version 1.8.3`

`Package.swift` is in the root folder so I have no clue what the actual problem is. Anyone have any idea?
The package compiles fine and also the sample app works.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Figured it out.

`README.MD` should have been named `README.md`

Comment: I answered my own question with the problem I found I had and somehow I'm getting downvoted?

Comment: Your question did not include a code section that referenced the changed command described in this answer. Just a guess as to why the down votes - not from me.

Answer (score 12):

Make new `Release` on Github. SPM read `Release`

Comment: Awesome!! I just create new tag and it working!

Comment: Solved it for me! I created a new `Release` on GitHub - that was essentially pushed a new `tag` to `origin`. See [official GitHub page](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/about-releases) for more info.

Answer (score 8):

For me the solution below worked:

In Xcode: `File -> Swift Packages -> Reset Package Caches`

this is probably for the case where the conflicting package has previously been added with the other version

Comment: What about in **AppCode**?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, which was caused by how my folders were organize.

I had the following structure:

- Package_Name

  - Package_Name

    - Sources/Package_Name
    - Tests/Package_Name_Tests
    - Package.swift

I created a folder before creating the package on Xcode, so it was duplicated. When I removed the former, that I created. Everything worked fine.

So, remember of leaving your `Package.swift` at root folder.

Comment: when we create Swift Package it creates a folder and Package.swift inside it. when we try to access that repo it complains about Package.swift not present